# Not able to send values from Froala WYSIWYG editor in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, editor, froala

I'm working with Froala WYSIWYG editor i want to pass data to another page but my button is completely disable. when i press button the action is still the page is not transferred.

```
<div id="editor">
        <?php

        if(!empty($_SESSION['success']))
        {
            echo "done completely";
        }
                // Create connection
                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
                // Check connection
                if (!$conn) {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }

                else{
                $sql = "select * from user_login where id= 6";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
                {

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){



        ?>
        <form action='try.php' method='post' >
          <textarea id='edit' style="margin-top: 30px;" placeholder="Type some text" name='user_name'>
            <?php echo  $row["user_name"] ; ?>
          </textarea>


      <input name='submit' type="submit" value='Success' class="btn btn-success" />  
        </form>

            <?php

                    }
                }   
            }

        ?>  
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Jquery to extract the HTML Content from your Editor. Than you can Post it to your Server.
https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/getHTML

Jquery Code:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(e){
    var helpHtml = $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor('html.get'); // Froala Editor Inhalt auslesen
    $.post( "otherPage.php", { helpHtml:helpHtml });
});
```

In PHP you will have the Content in your $_POST.

Don't forget to add the id-attribute to your button ( id='submitButton')

Also be aware of single quotes in the editor content when saving with simple SQL-Queries.

Answer (score 0):

I was a week trying to solve the same problem and the answer was so easy!!
The code for the editor is the next:

```
<form action="save.php" method="POST">


<textarea name="editor_content" id="myEditor"></textarea>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#myEditor').froalaEditor({toolbarInline: false})
  });
</script>
```

Also make sure that you include all the css and js files.

In the save.php file you can get the data with $_POST['editor_content'];